# Player disconnects from the game due to lost wss connection

Tags: javascript

WS package is added to our Node js library. We connect to the socket via https with the help of PHP, but our wss server disconnects from time to time. DNS goes through cloudflare. SSL is active on the server side and on cloudflare. We cannot detect the problem of disconnection. What is your suggestion and opinion?

Here is the link section in index.php:

```
$gameIp = "mydomain.com;
                    $gamePortforFfa = "1001";
                    echo '<option id="vs-1" value="'.$gameIp.'/vs-1">VS-1</option>';
```

Below is the relevant part in main.js:

```
function wsConnect() {
        sid = Math.floor(1+Math.random()*1000000);
        wsUrl = "wss://" + CONNECTION_URL;// + "/" + sid;
        nodesOnScreen = [];
        playerCells = [];
        nodes = {};
        nodelist = [];
        Cells = [];
        leaderBoard = [];
        lastWinner = '?';
        this.countdown = 3600;
        mainCanvas = teamScores = null;
        userScoreMax = 0;
        userScoreCurrent = 0;
        teamMapPlayers = [];
        clanMapPlayers = [];
        
        ws = new WebSocket(wsUrl);
        ws.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
        ws.onopen = onWsOpen;
        ws.onmessage = onWsMessage;
        ws.onclose = onWsClose;
        ws.onerror = function () {
            console.log("socket error");
        }
    }
```

The console records resulting from the disconnection are shown in the images below:

[image: Error1]

[image: Error2]

We tried the recommendations suggested as a result of different research. but we could not reach the result.
Additionally, after the player is disconnected from the game, he cannot re-enter the game.
Below is a diagram showing the error log we received with pm2.

[image: Log]